# Titleize without Downcasing

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Ruby 2.1.3 and Rails 4.1.6.
I have been using .titleize to clean up some user input such as

```
'new york'.titleize
 => "New York"
```

However, titleize can also break correct user input by downcasing when not desired:

```
'New York, NY'.titleize
 => "New York, Ny"
```

Is there a clean way to titleize without any downcasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect mix case words and want to keep them mix cased I would something like this:

```
def titleize_without_downcasing(string)
  string.gsub(/(\w|')(\w*)/) { $1.upcase + $2 }
end

titleize_without_downcasing('new york, NY, UsA')
#=> 'New York, NY, UsA'

titleize_without_downcasing("doctor's")
#=> "Doctor's"
```

Comment: This is what the OP wants. The title says: *Titleize without Downcasing*. I ensure that I do not change words by calling `titleize` that are already upcase.

Comment: True, +1 to your answer. :)

Comment: I just don't understand this line of code `string.gsub(/(\w)(\w*)/) { |word| $1.upcase + $2 }` could you explain it?

Comment: The Regexp would match the same words. But having two capture groups  `()` instead of just one makes the handling of the first character (catched in `$1`) and the rest of the word (in `$2`) a bit easier. `$1.upcase + $2` reads as: Always upcase the first character (came from `(\w)`) and then add the rest of the word (from `(\w*)`) without any change.

Comment: titleize_without_downcasing is what I was looking for. Thanks! The other option didn't work, as pointed out: titleize_respecting_abbr('new york, NY, UsA')
 => "New York, NY, Us A" (unwanted space added)

Comment: @pgarber: I removed my first example, that didn't work for all edge cases. IT added the extra whitespace because of an unexpected behaviour in Rails' titleize method: `'UsA'.titleize` returns "Us A". I wasn't aware the `titleize` splits words like that. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def titlize(str)
  r = str.split.map { |word| word.size > 2 ? word.titleize : word.capitalize }
  r.join(" ")
end
```

Comment: What about `"New York, NY, USA"`?